# caching in puppeteer is not working as expected

Tags: python, c#, google-chrome, caching, puppeteer

i've recently made a script for puppeteer that navigates to my site and scraps the main index, on my chrome browser, using incognito, at first it loads the page entirely, and then, when i want to access the same page again, it's loaded by cache, reducing usage by a lot, but this doesn't happen in puppeteer, so it loads everything everytime i want to access the page, i've even created a folder that the argument "--user-data-dir" uses to save things like cache, but it still doesn't load most stuff from cache

I haven't tried much since i don't know how this could be fixed

Comment: Please share a [mcve]. How is this both Python and C#?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.